# How can I dump all the source code from a Squeak Smalltalk image?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I’ve downloaded [the source code](http://info.scratch.mit.edu/Source_Code) of Scratch, which is written in [Squeak Smalltalk](http://squeak.org/). I can browse the source in Squeak, but what I really want is a big text file. The image is based on Squeak 2.8.

I’m a total Squeak newbie. So far, I’m loving it, and my impression of the language and environment is that dumping all the source code in this image to a file can probably be done in about 3 lines of code, if only I knew my way around better. Can you supply the 3 lines of code?

I won’t complain if it ends up being 4 lines (or more likely, 1 line).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Untested, but:

```
Smalltalk allClasses do: [:each | each fileOut]
```

This should dump three million .st files, named after each class in the system.

Welcome and happy smalltalking!

**EDIT:**
As it seems, this wouldn't work in early squeaks, I've been testing around and it looks the following should work in a Scratch source code image:

```
SystemOrganization categories do: [:each | SystemOrganization fileOutCategory: each]
```

Comment: And now for bonus points: check all existing objects in the image to see if source is available, otherwise decompile.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, but this is what I'd do: |allClassNames|
allClassNames := Smalltalk allClasses collect: [:each| each className]. "We store it first to save us computing time"
(Object allSubInstances select: [:each | (allClassNames includes: each class) not]) do: [:each | each doWhateverYouNeedToDo]